# OO JavaScript, how do I improve this Class? Is there a better, cleaner way of doing it?

Tags: javascript, oop

I had a function, that would accept multiple arguments.

```
function formatString(Number, option1, option2, option3, option4, option5) {
  // apply options to the string:
  // eg: format to '0.00', append "+", append £ sign etc
  // return formatted Number as String
}
```

All options were optional, so it started to become a little difficult to use and understand what it does:

```
formatString(value, null, true, currency, null, true) // thats bad
```

So I began thinking how could I make it easier to use, to extend and to understand. I came up with a Class:

```
export default class Amount {
  constructor(value) {
    this.value = value;
  }

  set coin(val) {
    this._coin = val;
  }

  set currency(val) {
    this._currency = val;
  }

  set format(format) {
    this._format = format;
  }

  set withCurrencySymbol(val) {
    this._withCurrencySymbol = val;
  }

  set prependPlusOrMinus(val) {
    this._prependPlusOrMinus = val;
  }

  get formatted() {
    let { value } = this;
    if (this._coin && this._currency) {
      value = this.coinToCurrency(this.value, this._coin, this._currency);
    }

    let formatted = `${numeral(Math.abs(value)).format(this._format)}`;
    if (this._currency) formatted = `${currencySymbols[this._currency]}${formatted}`;

    if (this._prependPlusOrMinus) {
      if (value < 0) return `&#45; ${formatted}`;
      if (value > 0) return `&#43; ${formatted}`;
    }

    return formatted;
  }

  coinToCurrency() {
    const { rate } = exchangeRates[this._coin].find(item => item.currency === this._currency);
    return this.value * rate;
  }
}
```

It makes it easier to use:

```
  const amount = new Amount(value);
  amount.currency = currency;
  amount.format = format;
  console.log(amount.formatted);
```

You only have to set the options you want to set and it's easier to understand at a glance.

I was wondering, is there a better way of doing it though? Any tips?

Thanks!

Comment: A common approach is using and options object and pass it to the constructor `new Amount({currency, format, somethingElse: true})`

Comment: Once you pass like 3-4 parameters, people usually use an object, so you can add as much parameters you want without having to change the function signature. THen destructuring can be used to easily turn that obejct back into the seperate variables.

Comment: thats one option, seems like, thanks

Comment: Initialise your properties in the constructor, don't rely on setters to define them.

Comment: It looks like you don't need a `class` at all. There is nothing that needs an instance with multiple methods or OOP state. Just write a plain function and use an [options object argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11457449/when-to-use-which-multiple-methods-multiple-parameters-or-an-options-paramet).

Comment: Might also be interesting to consider the spread operator.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is better to pass the parameters as an Object,{value:val, currency:cur...}. 
and use a default configuration in the constructor to decrease the number of parameters to enter while using this class.

This is an example with one property you can do the same for the other properties

```js
class Amount {
    constructor(opt){
      const defaultOpts= {currency:'$'}
      this.opts=Object.assign(defaultOpts,opt)
    }
    
    getValueWithCurruency(){
      return this.opts.value+this.opts.currency
    }
    
}
    
const foo= new Amount({value:50})    
console.log(foo.getValueWithCurruency())//50$

const fooEuro= new Amount({value:50,currency:"€"})  
console.log(fooEuro.getValueWithCurruency())//50€
```